# Adding an item to react state dictionary

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add an item to a react state dictionary. Every time i press to submit i got the value is undefined on the dictionary object and it is append to the dictonary with a null values in name and cost but id is working fine.  I find the issue but i am unable to find the solution. TIA.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem.js";


class ExpensesList extends Component {
state = {
  expenses: [{id: '12345' ,name: 'Pizza', cost: '20'}],
};

handleChange=(event)=>{
this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
}
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); 

  this.setState({expenses: [this.state.expenses,...[{id: Math.random(),name:this.state.expenses.name, cost:this.state.expense.cost}]]});

}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <ul className="list-group">
    {this.state.expenses.map((expense) => (
      <ExpenseItem
        id={expense.id}
        name={expense.name}
        cost={expense.cost}
      />
    ))}
  </ul>
  <div className ="row mt-3">
  <h2> Add Expenses </h2>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input
          required="required"
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="name"
          value = {this.state.expenses.name}
          onChange = {this.handleChange}
        ></input>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label for="name">Cost</label>
        <input
          required="required"
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="cost"
          value = {this.state.expenses.cost}
          onChange = {this.handleChange}
        ></input>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary"> Add Expense</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  
  </div>
  
  
);
}
}

export default ExpensesList;
```

Comment: You are radically changing the structure of the state in handleSubmit and in handleChange. Math.random() is a bad way to get unique ids. Why are you creating, then spreading a single value array?

Answer (score 2):

The issues is that `this.state.expenses` is an array. So, `this.state.expenses.name` and `this.state.expenses.cost` are both undefined.

If you want to be able to add new expense objects to the `expenses` array in state, you need a way to manage the new inputs in state. So, your state should look something like this:

```
state = {
  expenses: [{id: '12345' ,name: 'Pizza', cost: '20'}],
  cost: "",
  name: ""
};
```

When a user inputs a cost and name, `this.state.cost` and `this.state.name` should be set in state, and then when the user clicks 'submit', a new object can be added to the `this.state.expenses` array.

(Also, your handleChange needs to specify which properties of state it intends to udpate)

Your final solution should look something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem.js";


class ExpensesList extends Component {
    state = {
        expenses: [{ id: '12345', name: 'Pizza', cost: '20' }],
        cost: "",
        name: ""
    };

    handleChange = (event, name) => {
       this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
    };

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        let newExpense = {
           id: Math.random(),
           name: this.state.name,
           cost: this.state.cost
        }

        this.setState(prevState => ({
           expenses: [...prevState.expenses, newExpense],   // add new expense to expenses array
           cost: "", // reset this field
           name: "" // reset this field
        }));

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.state.expenses.map((expense) => (
                        <ExpenseItem
                            id={expense.id}
                            name={expense.name}
                            cost={expense.cost}
                        />
                    ))}
                </ul>
                <div className="row mt-3">
                    <h2> Add Expenses </h2>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input
                                    required="required"
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="name"
                                    value={this.state.name}
                                    onChange={e => this.handleChange("name")}
                                ></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Cost</label>
                                <input
                                    required="required"
                                    type="text"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="cost"
                                    value={this.state.cost}
                                    onChange={e => this.handleChange("cost")}
                                ></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary"> Add Expense</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>


        );
    }
}

export default ExpensesList;
```